# Is a checkride signoff still good after a year?

Tags: ppl, checkride

I was signed off to take the private pilot check ride. I got Covid and didn’t take it
It’s been 1 yr are those sign offs still good.

Comment: I assume this is about the US? You may want to talk to your instructor, they may want to have you run through some refresher. Not passing that test also affects them...

Comment: So your saying all the sign offs are good I just need some more time is that right

Answer (score 5):

This is for the FAA...

The endorsement in your log book reads:

> I certify that [First name, MI, Last name] has received and logged training time **within 2 calendar-months preceding the month of application** in preparation for the practical test and [he or she] is prepared for the required practical test for the issuance of [applicable] certificate.

So while the endorsement does not expire per-se, you are required to have training within 2 months of the *application*. If you got the endorsement *and applied for the practical test* within 2 months, then you are OK.

However the reality is that you probably need to have a quick hour or two with your instructor again and they will re-certify the endorsement. I'm guessing your application either wasn't made, or the application itself expired.

Answer (score 0):

(With respect to the U.S.): In effect, in my opinion, some of the required "sign-offs" (endorsements) **do expire**.

Specifically, [14 CFR 61.39(a)(6)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.39(a)(6)) states (in pertinent part):

> Have an endorsement, if required by this part, in the applicant's logbook or training record that has been signed by an authorized instructor who certifies that the applicant -
>
> > (i) Has received and logged training time within 2 calendar months preceding the month of application in preparation for the practical test;

According to [AC 61-65H](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/ac_61-65h.pdf) - Certification: Pilots and Flight and Ground Instructors, (sample endorsement A.1 on page A-6), this endorsement would look something like:

> I certify that [First name, MI, Last name] has received and logged training time within
> 2 calendar-months preceding the month of application in preparation for the practical test and [he or she] is prepared for the required practical test for the issuance of [applicable] certificate.

This endorsement would only be valid if the training time actually occurred within 2 calendar-months preceding the the month of application (when you apply/appear for the practical test).  This would mean that if you received the endorsement and you and the instructor signed the 8710-1 application, you could not wait around for few months and then schedule the test with an examiner and rely on the fact that you completed the "application" and received the training months earlier and therefore "applied" for the test and completed the training within 2 calendar months preceding the month of the test.

---

Also, according to [14 CFR 61.109(a)(4)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.109(a)(4)), which states (in pertinent part):

> 3 hours of flight training with an authorized instructor in a single-engine airplane in preparation for the practical test, which must have been performed within the preceding 2 calendar months from the month of the **test**; (emphasis is mine)

The endorsement would look something like:

> I certify that [First name, MI, Last name] has received the required training in accordance
> with §§ 61.107 and 61.109. I have determined [he or she] is prepared for the [name of]
> practical test.

This endorsement (sign-off) is number A.33 on page A-11 of AC 61-65H (see the link above) and is **required in addition to the endorsement required under FAR 61.39 (a)(6)** shown above.

So, again, these endorsements and the associated training have to be current as of the date of the test.  Therefore, it's my opinion that you would need to have these endorsements dated within the time frame "within 2 calendar months preceding the month of application in preparation for the practical test."

Since you had a 1 year gap these previous endorsements have effectively expired and need to be re-done (and the associated training completed within the dates specified).

Lastly, you may want to check the date that you passed the Private Pilot written test to ensure that it is still valid (see [14 CFR 61.39(a)(1)(i)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.39(a)(1)(i)).